# React bind function to each item inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make it so when you click on the dropdown arrow the settings dropdown will appear.

When I currently press an arrow dropdown, all the settings dropdown open that are within the array loop.

[image: all thee dropdowns]

This is the function that renders the loop:

```
viewPublishedPages() {

    const pages = this.state.pages;

    return (
      <div>
        {pages.map((val, i) => {
          let dropdown = 'none';
          return (
            <div className="block" key={i}>
              <div className="columns">
                <div className="column is-10">
                  <p>PUBLISHED</p>
                  <h2>{val.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="column">
                  <div className="settings">
                    <div className="arrow__container">
                      <div className="arrow" onClick={this.showSettings.bind(this, i)} />
                    </div>
                    {
                      this.state.settingPanel 
                        ?
                        <ClickOutside onClickOutside={::this.hide}>
                        <div className="arrow__dropdown">
                          <Link href={{pathname: '/admin/edit-page', query: {title: val.title}}}>
                            <a className="arrow__dropdown__link">Edit</a>
                          </Link>
                          <button
                            className="arrow__dropdown__delete"
                            onClick={() => this.handleDelete(i)}>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        </ClickOutside> 
                        : null
                    }

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Notice: `<div className="arrow" onClick={this.showSettings.bind(this, i)} />`

This is the state:

```
  static dataStruc () {
    return {
      loading: true,
      settingPanel: false,
      pages: [],
    };
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: @mersocarlin it should only show the dropdown to the corresponding "page". Currently when I press the dropdown it opens both settings panel.

Comment: Could you provide a sample on how does `this.state.pages` look like?

Comment: It's a bit confusing though. Your are looping through and array of pages (`pages.map(...)`) and for each one your have to render this dropdown?

Comment: @mersocarlin i added what the state looks like

Comment: @mersocarlin ya exactly. i'm looping through the pages array and need to show the dropdown for the corresponding page withing the array. I'm guessing I'd need to attach an index, but wouldn't binding to that page within the loop be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are currently saving a `boolean` value to `settingPanel` and therefore all dropdowns open upon click.

My suggestion is replace `settingPanel` from `boolean` to the respective page `id`. In case you don't have page ids, then store the current page `index` on it.

That makes it easier to render the dropdown so you have access/control to the selected one and later render its settings:

```
showSettings(index) {
  this.setState({
    settingPanel: index,
  })
}
```

And then in `viewPublishedPages`:

```
{this.state.settingPanel === i && 
  <ClickOutside onClickOutside={::this.hide}>
    ..
  </ClickOutside>}
```

I wrote a sample code so you get the idea.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      pages: [
        { title: 'Home' },
        { title: 'Contact' },
        { title: 'Page' }
      ],
      settingPanel: -1,
    }

    this.showSettings = this.showSettings.bind(this)
  }

  showSettings(index) {
     this.setState({
       settingPanel: this.state.settingPanel === index ? -1 : index,
     })
  }

  render() {
    const { pages, settingPanel } = this.state
    
    return (
      <div>
        {pages.map((page, index) =>
          <div key={index} className="page">
            <div onClick={this.showSettings.bind(this, index)}>
              {page.title}
            </div>
            {settingPanel === index &&
              <div className="settings">
                <div>Setting 1</div>
                <div>Setting 2</div>
                <div>Setting 3</div>
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.page {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.settings {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. Def makes sense. Thought binding would do this behind the scenes.